Flutter: AppLifecycleState inactive with system dialog open (Detect foreground vs minimized)
In Flutter, the AppLifecycleState becomes AppLifecycleState.inactive when a system dialog is opened, even though the app remains visible in the foreground. This makes it difficult to distinguish between the app being truly minimized and simply having a system dialog active.
Is there a reliable way to determine if a Flutter app is truly in the foreground (with a system dialog open) or minimized/in the background when the AppLifecycleState is AppLifecycleState.inactive?
